# Working with Blogger Or WordPress does make any difference in my site ranking?

Tags: wordpress, blogger

I started writing Articles in blogger. Now I purchased a new domain. Now I am confused that I should go with Blogger or Wordpress. If I attach my website with blogger and post my Articles, does this makes any difference with working on Wordpress? I mean does it affect my site ranking if I go with Blogger? I am more comfortable with Blogger.

Comment: No it does not affect your site ranking

Comment: Site ranking are based on SEO if you maintain your site with SEO then it's does't affect you google ranking.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to the Web Applications Stack Exchange ( https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ )

Answer (score 0):

Blogger has no options for plugins and utilities to enhance SEO. If that is something important to you WordPress will provide many more options to implement things like schema and custom meta tags etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Search Engine Ranking is independent of the platform, you can do the same job in blogger and WordPress. But on WordPress, there are plugins which make it easier to do and which results that you will spend much less time compared to blogger.